# Is there a way of having Woocommerce Order Confirmation emails display product info in a PDF?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

To expand on the title, i've build a 'quote builder' that has multiple custom fields, and if someone wanted say 10 quotes, the email body will be quite large. (Attached image is one quote, no CSS is working to align those next to each other for some reason).

So we just want instead of the the product date coming through into the body of the email, can it be added to a PDF as an attachment instead?

Comment: try with this free plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/